# What is an FLR file?

Tags: media-files

When I was going through files in an app, I found some files with **.flr** extension. I found these files in the **asset** directory.

When I did some research, I find out that it's associated with some animation in Flutter. When I opened it with a text editor, it was some gibberish beginning with **FLARE**.

How can I view that animation?

Comment: I decompiled the app using apktool

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the [Flare](https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter)  project or the successor [Rive](https://rive.app)? Those projects can be found easily using the keywords you provided.